# Is there a KVM switch that plays audio from all connections?

Tags: audio, kvm-switch

My PC is set up with Xen.  It is running two DomU's, both with a VGA card exposed.  One domain is going to get the sound card on the motherboard and the other is going to get a USB audio card.

I would like to hook them both up to a KVM switch.  However, I want the audio to play from both domains at all times.  I do not want the KVM switch to only play audio from the current view.

Is there a KVM switch out there that does this?  If not, is there a device that will mix the audio from two inputs?

Comment: I've decided to ditch Xen for QEMU, which has better audio support, but if anyone has an answer, I'd like to hear it.